# Saving Entity Framework object is deleting existing one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an information page which is being posted to database using Entity Framework. Everything is fine but when I initially enter a record and hit save twice, the record is deleted from database (it actually saves after first save click). This problem doesn't reflect for modifying and occurs for new entry.

Here is my code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody]CandidateLanding landing)
{
    var result = await candidateContext.CandidateLanding
                       .Where(x => x.UserID == id)
                       .AsNoTracking()
                       .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (result != null)
    {
        if (landing.ID == 0)
        {
            landing.ID = result.ID;
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (landing.ID > 0)
        {
            candidateContext.Entry(landing).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            landing.UserID = id;

            candidateContext.CandidateLanding.Add(landing);
        }

        await candidateContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = landing.ID }, landing);
}
```

Comment: It's not totally clear to me, but based on the code, if a user double clicks I would expect it to first execute the .Add(landing) code and then, the second time through, execute the .State = modified code.  Is that correct?

Comment: If you create a new landing, which value does the id parameter have? Is the id column in the database an auto inc column?

Comment: @stephen.vakil..exactly you are correct. and .Add(landing) will execute only first time when user creates a row.

Comment: @Martin..yes martin its auto inc column from DB.

Comment: @stephen.vakil..exactly you are correct. and .Add(landing) will execute only first time when user creates a row. If I modify any exixsting record and double click then it works fine. This happens only with new record.